# Sending Email disable/fixed mailto and subject,i.e., this two sections are not editable format. Is this possible?

Tags: java, android, email

I am unable to disable mailto and subject section when the intent comes on email section, but I need this two section fixed from my programming part. For an example

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Here I want mail will be send only "abc@gmail.com" and user will not be able to edit this thing or not to put another email id. Same case for subject also.

Is this possible? Please suggest me.

Comment: Sorry dude. I totally miss understood your question. 
This is not possible to be fixed the email and subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that would be possible as you are just launching a third party application which your application have no control over. If you want to implement that feature in your app then you should use an SMTP library to send an email without user intervention.

This [article](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to send the email via intent in android device.

```
String data = "EMAIL MESSAGE";
Intent intentSendMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentSendMail.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intentSendMail.setType("message/rfc822");
intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" });
intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intentSendMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentSendMail, "Send email..."));
```

**NOTE:**

1. This is only worked when you have installed at-least 1 mail client LIKE "`EMAIL`" or "`GMAIL`" in your device.
2. This will not worked in the simulator try with real device.

Comment: No. as per my knowledge this is not possible. Because the email client is not handled by our application. Our application is only able to pass the values to them.